# Excel VBA does not find a DLL-file programmed by myself

Tags: c++, dll, registry

in Excel-VBA I programmed a small production planning front-end which calls a wrapper (dll programmed in C++, Visual Studio 2022), which in turn calles Autonester-x64.dll (a commercial solver to optimaly nest shapes). On two Windows 10 machines this works fine. On the third computer, which is used in production, it does not work:
(1) The excel VBA-program raises the error "File not found"
(2) If I try to register the wrapper.dll, it raises the following error:

[error message from regsvr32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlNKl.png)

Of course, regarding (1) I carefully checked the file locations about 10 times, so this can not be the cause. I then thought, lets get rid of the problem by registering the dll -- but without success. Its so stupid, but I have no more ideas what I could try to solve it... Any help is most welcome!

Comment: Please post the error message as formatted text, so that it can be used by search engines and seen by those who can't necessarily load images.

Answer (score 0):

This message from the Windows DLL loader is useless junk. I would first check the Office version (x32 or x64).

Take a look at the [DllManager VBA class](https://pchemguy.github.io/DllTools/). Maybe it will help. I use it to load DLLs on Windows 10 from a user folder without any registration. It also runs a few basic checks, and it might provide a more useful error message.

Comment: I found the problem: the path to the autonester.dll (called by the wrapper.dll), needed to be included in the path environment-variable. That solved this strange behaviour.